# Angular 4 - my app freezes after printing html document of Material MDDialog component using window.print()

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I am trying to print html document of Material MDDialog component using 
window.print() as showed bellow in the code, it's working perfectly but, the problem starts when the print window is getting close and after that nothing is working and my app freezes I mean nothing works like (closing the Dialog, clicking link...) I think the problem is with changing the body tag innerHTML but don't know how to solve it ?

```
export class someClass {

@ViewChild('printContent') printContent;

    printDocument() {
        const restorePage = document.body.innerHTML;
        const content = this.printContent.nativeElement.innerHTML;
        document.body.innerHTML = content;
        window.print();
        document.body.innerHTML = restorePage;

      }
}
```

Comment: Couldn't you just add `display: none` to the content you don't want to be printed? I believe browsers are smart enough to understand that they don't need to print that part.

Comment: I am trying to just print html document of Material MDDialog not whole page can you give me more description please

Comment: What I mean is: just before `window.print()`, hide ALL content you DON'T want to print. Afterwards, show it again.

Comment: I have 100 contents in this page you mean I should hide one by one or there is some solution with javascript FYI what is the problem with my code is there any solution to my code?

Comment: You could make a css class: `body.print-mode * :not[.printable] { display: none; }`. Add a `printable` class to the elements you want to print. Add the `print-mode` class to your `body` tag before `window.print()` is called, and remove it afterwards. That should hide all elements without `.printable`.

Comment: Aha! I got you, u mean, I should ignore this line of code in my code  document.body.innerHTML = content; instead I should add print-mode class to body before window.print() and remove print-mode class from body after print window closed

Comment: Yes, I mean that! If you give me a few mins, I'll create an answer that'll show what I mean more clearly.

Comment: great I am waiting for you are answer

Comment: I tried not working

Answer (score 1):

You should add a CSS declaration:

```
@media print {
  .hidden-print {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

Give this class to all elements you want to **hide** from the printer. In your `printDocument` function, you only need window.print().

`@media print` is used in a printer context, and is built-in in css. The declaration itself is built-in in Bootstrap, **so if you use Bootstrap**, you just need to add `hidden-print` class to elements, you don't need to define it yourself.

Comment: Yes I **use Bootstrap** after executing this code `document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]
      .classList.add('hidden-print');
    window.print();` the blank page is getting print and also, as you mentioned the solution in above comments `body.print-mode * :not (.printable) { display: none !important;  }` it's not working.

Comment: You don't need `document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0] .classList.add('hidden-print');`, just directly add it to your html. You're getting a blank page still?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding css styles in print mode to the original Material MDDialog dives as bellow showed in the code. If some one wants to preview the page to be printed in MDDialog after want to print the MDDialog component Content this code will be helpful. thanks @Jeff Huijsmans for you are help.

```
@media print {
  body.print-mode > *:not(.printable) {
    visibility: hidden !important;
    padding: 0px !important;
    margin: 0px !important;
  }
  body.print-mode {
    padding: 0px !important;
    margin: 0px !important;
  }

  .printable {
    padding: 0px !important;
    margin: 0px !important;
    width: 100% !important;
  }
  .mat-dialog-container {
    max-width: none !important;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }

  }
  .printable {
    position: absolute !important;
    overflow:visible !important;
    visibility: visible !important;
  }
  .cdk-overlay-container{
    padding: 0px !important;
    margin: 0px !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    position: absolute !important;
    overflow:visible !important;
    visibility: visible !important;
  }
  .cdk-overlay-pane{
    padding: 0px !important;
    margin: 0px !important;
    width: 100% !important;
  }
}
```